# Composite REST - INVALID_BATCH_REQUEST - Cannot access this resource in a batch request

Tags: rest-api

**(I was having an issue, it took me awhile to figure it out, and the Google search results and Salesforce documentation wasn't helping - so I'm posting this question, and the answer to my problem, so Google can provide better search results for anyone else having this issue)**

I'm POSTing a Composite REST API call. My JSON looks like this:

```
{
"batchRequests": [
    {
        "method": "PATCH",
        "url": "/v47.0/composite/sobjects/Opportunity/0064P00000nR2yBZAS",
        "richInput": {
            "pymt__Shipping__c": "4.95",
            "pymt__Tax__c": "0",
            "CloseDate": "2020-01-11"
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/v47.0/composite/sobjects/OpportunityLineItem",
        "richInput": {
            "OpportunityId": "0064P00000nR2yBZAS",
            "UnitPrice": "49.95",
            "Quantity": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/v47.0/composite/sobjects/OpportunityLineItem",
        "richInput": {
            "OpportunityId": "0064P00000nR2yBZAS",
            "UnitPrice": "59.95",
            "Quantity": "1"
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/v47.0/composite/sobjects/OpportunityLineItem",
        "richInput": {
            "OpportunityId": "0064P00000nR2yBZAS",
            "UnitPrice": "34.95",
            "Quantity": "1"
        }
    }
]}
```

My response is:

```
    {
  "hasErrors": true,
  "results": [
    {
      "result": [
        {
          "errorCode": "INVALID_BATCH_REQUEST",
          "message": "Cannot access this resource in a batch request"
        }
      ],
      "statusCode": 400
    },
    {
      "result": [
        {
          "errorCode": "INVALID_BATCH_REQUEST",
          "message": "Cannot access this resource in a batch request"
        }
      ],
      "statusCode": 400
    },
    {
      "result": [
        {
          "errorCode": "INVALID_BATCH_REQUEST",
          "message": "Cannot access this resource in a batch request"
        }
      ],
      "statusCode": 400
    },
    {
      "result": [
        {
          "errorCode": "INVALID_BATCH_REQUEST",
          "message": "Cannot access this resource in a batch request"
        }
      ],
      "statusCode": 400
    }
  ]}
```

Why is it saying **INVALID_BATCH_REQUEST** and "*Cannot access this resource in a batch request*"?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you're providing the wrong URIs, which is why Salesforce "*Can't access the resource*".

You were probably looking at [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections.htm), and saw "***/vXX.X/composite/sobjects***". and thought your Batch request URIs were supposed to have "/composite/" in them - they're not.

If you change your URIs to "***/v47.0/sobjects/OpportunityLineItem***" (as shown on [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_batch.htm#topic-title)), they should work.